# The direct product of the geometric fundamental group and the absolute Galois group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, fundamental-group

Given a geometrically connected variety $X$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ we have a short exact sequence
$$
1\to \pi_1(X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}})\to \pi_1(X)\to Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\to 1.
$$
A rational point on $X$ provides a splitting of this sequence i.e. it exhibits $\pi_1(X)$ as a semidirect product of $\pi_1(X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}})$ and the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$. Does there exist a smooth and proper variety (to avoid trivialities with an infinite geometric fundamental group) such that $\pi_1(X)$ is actually the direct product of these two groups? Is there an example where such a splitting comes from a rational point?

Comment: Does complex conjugation ever act trivially on a nontrivial fundamental group of a variety?

Comment: @KevinCasto Maybe there is a variety with $\pi_1 = \mathbb{Z}/2$?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Fair enough -- I guess I really had in mind the setting of the question, with an infinite fundamental group

Comment: @KevinCasto is your objection that conjugation has to interchange $H^{1, 0}$ and $H^{0, 1}$? Could the fundamental group be perfect to avoid that?

Comment: [@TheoJohnson-Freyd](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349135/the-direct-product-of-the-geometric-fundamental-group-and-the-absolute-galois-gr#comment874614_349135), the fundamental group of $\operatorname{SL}_2$ is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ (but it's not proper).

Comment: @vrz Yes, that was part of it. Mostly I just couldn't think of any examples where it acts trivially! And analytically, conjugation certainly acts nontrivially on the loop space, so you'd have to cook things up so that it takes loops to homotopic loops.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd An Enriques surface has geometric fundamental group of order $2$.

Comment: There are non-smooth examples, like the cubic $y^2 =x^3 -x^2$.

Comment: Both $SL_2$ and many Enriques surfaces are examples, because they have a geometrically nontrivial double cover defined over $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 4):

If $X$ is an abelian variety, then it is not a direct product. For example, because the absolute galois group cannot act trivially on the torsion points (e.g. by Mordell-Weil). It follows that it is not a direct product for any $X$ with a non-trivial Albanese.